# How to achieve the screen using Graphical Editing Framework in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-gef

I want to achieve the GUI represents in the link provided http://www.eclipse.org/gef/.
I want that kind of view as drag and drop.
Is there any resource available to get that kind of screen. I tried the snippets available for Zest already. But my objective is to get the drag and drop of buttons to the editor window as a GUI Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check UML project for Eclipse, probably you need something like that... 
[link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html)
[image]